# Sending events between components

Tags: reactjs

Consider the ToDo App example on the React homepage.  For posterity, here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nXJL5/) and the code is at the end of this post.

Now say we decide to upgrade this app with w simple features:

1. Each todo item will have not only text, but also a "done" attribute.  You can click on an item and it will toggle the "done" state, and perhaps add strikethrough styling when it is done.
2. At the very bottom, there will be text indicating the number of "Done", eg, "2 items done, 3 left to do"

The problem is that the state of the items is maintained in `TodoApp`, not in `TodoList`.  So we'd like to add an `onClick={something}` to the `<li>` element in `TodoList`'s render method.  But we want that click event to be handled by `TodoApp`, which would then change the state of the item, and cause everything to re-render.  If we wanted to approach it like this, how could we do it?

We could also create a `TodoItem` component to be called by `TodoList`, and push the statefulness down into that.  This would allow the click to be handled by the `TodoItem`, but now we would need a way to share the `TodoItem`s' states with the component indicating the number of items done and still todo.

In a nutshell, I'd like to know how components can send events to each other, because I think just knowing that would allow solutions to both problems.

### React ToDo App

```js
/** @jsx React.DOM */
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(itemText) {
      return <li>{itemText}</li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem)}</ul>;
  }
});
var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  onChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  handleSubmit: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var nextItems = this.state.items.concat([this.state.text]);
    var nextText = '';
    this.setState({items: nextItems, text: nextText});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>TODO</h3>
        <TodoList items={this.state.items} />
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.text} />
          <button>{'Add #' + (this.state.items.length + 1)}</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
React.renderComponent(<TodoApp />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idiomatic way to do this is to pass a callback down to TodoList:

**Live demo:** http://jsbin.com/zeqizene/1/edit

I've changed TodoList to look like this:

```
var TodoList = React.createClass({
  handleDoneToggle: function(i) {
    this.props.onDoneToggle(i);
  },
  render: function() {
    var createItem = function(item, i) {
      return <li onClick={this.handleDoneToggle.bind(null, i)}>
        {item.text}
        {item.done && " (done)"}
      </li>;
    };
    return <ul>{this.props.items.map(createItem, this)}</ul>;
  }
});
```

When an item is clicked, TodoList will call its own `onDoneToggle` function, so `TodoApp` can modify the state appropriately.

See also [Editing a rich data structure in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795323/editing-a-rich-data-structure-in-react-js).

Comment: Hey Ben, thanks very much.  I do see some drawback's to this approach.  In particular, what if you want to register multiple components to listen for a change?  You could imagine, eg, a "Stats" component that gave more detailed stats about your list.  And what if you knew there would be more "listener" components coming, but weren't sure yet what they'd be?  With this approach, would we be creating a container callback that looped through the individual "listener" callbacks, calling each one?  It seems like the ability to create and listen for custom events would make this easier...

Comment: Having multiple separate copies of the data is a good way to have inconsistencies in your UI where different parts show different data. It's better to have a single canonical data source (here, TodoApp) then pass that data through props and make calculations on it if necessary. Here I've added a TodoStats component which shows the number of items left: http://jsbin.com/zeqizene/3/edit. Because it gets its data from props directly, your UI is *guaranteed* to be in sync. We've found that custom events are much harder to reason about but you can implement them separately from React if you want.

Comment: Latest fiddle seems not to be working, I see this error in the console: `Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation`.  Going to check out the code now....

Comment: A few things still aren't sitting well with me.  1. Let's say I had a dynamic number Todo lists (think a Trello board) and the stats comp showed combined stats.  How are you solving this?  2. It feels very non-OO to have a monolithic data structure serving everything (maybe I'm misunderstanding you?).  To my mind, the more natural design is to have a TodoItem responsible for knowing it's own text and done state, and displaying that.  A TodoList knows hows to display items, delegating to them.  And TodoApp display a list and input & maybe stats.  Sort of an inversion of the original example.

Comment: Oh also to clarify my earlier suggestion about events, I never meant to imply having multiple copies of the data.  Each component is responsible for its own data and would provide relevant accessor methods to the other components as needed.  Triggering an event would tell interested parties to call back to the event origin to get any new data they needed.  Ie: the classic observer pattern.  Also, upvoted for your help.

Comment: 1. You can push the state up to a higher level so that the stats component can access it. See http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2013/11/05/thinking-in-react.html for a bit more on this topic. 2. In some ways, yes, but you can have each component treat the state it gets from its child as a black box. You can absolutely abstract out a TodoItem component and you should if it's at all complicated. You can also have a central store that triggers events for updates (this is approximately what Facebook does) -- the thing to avoid is having many views talk to each other and keep their own state.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I read the whole thing but I have to say I do not like it.  I can see some advantage to that approach, but pushing all your data skyward into one big blob at the top...  What happens when I need to add some new component that lives at the bottom leaves?  That change now propagates up all the parent components, who have to pass this new state data down until it gets to the new component, all the way up to the very top, where it alters the existing data structure.  With independent components communicating via events no such ripple effect occurs.  Am I missing something?

Comment: We've found that being explicit about exactly what data your components use helps with maintainability. This is no different from passing arguments through functions in regular code to make components reusable and avoid global state. That said, it sounds like you'd be happy with a central store -- have an object that stores the todo items and triggers an update event when it changes. http://cjlarose.com/2014/01/09/react-board-game-tutorial.html is a little bit like this. React is very flexible and doesn't impose any particular model structure on you -- feel free to use whatever you prefer.

Comment: I was actually suggesting the opposite of a central store (which is what the thinking in react way seems to be), and suggesting a more classically OO approach where each object is responsible for its own state.  You lose the all the data in one place (which does have some advantages), but gain a lot more resilience to change.  I will check out the link though, it seems interesting, and I like any approach that builds out a model first in pure JS.  Thanks again for all your help.